# Issue at compiling Caffe2

Tags: caffe

I try to compile caffe2 on my computer ( Ubuntu 17.1, CUDA 9.2), but I still get this error during linking:

```
[ 72%] Built target caffe2
[ 72%] Building NVCC (Device) object caffe2/CMakeFiles/caffe2_gpu.dir/sgd/caffe2_gpu_generated_yellowfin_op_gpu.cu.o
/home/john/pytorch/caffe2/sgd/yellowfin_op.h: In constructor ‘caffe2::YellowFinOp<T, Context>::YellowFinOp(const caffe2::OperatorDef&, caffe2::Workspace*)’:
/home/john/pytorch/caffe2/sgd/yellowfin_op.h:20:171: error: ‘GetSingleArgument<int>’ is not a member of ‘caffe2::YellowFinOp<T, Context>’
   YellowFinOp(const OperatorDef& operator_def, Workspace* ws)
                                                                                                                                                                           ^                      
/home/john/pytorch/caffe2/sgd/yellowfin_op.h:20:259: error: ‘GetSingleArgument<int>’ is not a member of ‘caffe2::YellowFinOp<T, Context>’
   YellowFinOp(const OperatorDef& operator_def, Workspace* ws)
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   ^                      
/home/john/pytorch/caffe2/sgd/yellowfin_op.h:20:347: error: ‘GetSingleArgument<bool>’ is not a member of ‘caffe2::YellowFinOp<T, Context>’
   YellowFinOp(const OperatorDef& operator_def, Workspace* ws)
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           ^                       
At global scope:
cc1plus: warning: unrecognized command line option ‘-Wno-aligned-allocation-unavailable’
cc1plus: warning: unrecognized command line option ‘-Wno-inconsistent-missing-override’
cc1plus: warning: unrecognized command line option ‘-Wno-unused-private-field’
cc1plus: warning: unrecognized command line option ‘-Wno-unknown-warning-option’
cc1plus: warning: unrecognized command line option ‘-Wno-typedef-redefinition’
cc1plus: warning: unrecognized command line option ‘-Wno-invalid-partial-specialization’
CMake Error at caffe2_gpu_generated_yellowfin_op_gpu.cu.o.Release.cmake:279 (message):
  Error generating file
  /home/john/pytorch/build/caffe2/CMakeFiles/caffe2_gpu.dir/sgd/./caffe2_gpu_generated_yellowfin_op_gpu.cu.o


caffe2/CMakeFiles/caffe2_gpu.dir/build.make:889: recipe for target 'caffe2/CMakeFiles/caffe2_gpu.dir/sgd/caffe2_gpu_generated_yellowfin_op_gpu.cu.o' failed
make[2]: *** [caffe2/CMakeFiles/caffe2_gpu.dir/sgd/caffe2_gpu_generated_yellowfin_op_gpu.cu.o] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:1441: recipe for target 'caffe2/CMakeFiles/caffe2_gpu.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [caffe2/CMakeFiles/caffe2_gpu.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:140: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Here is my system summary:

> --   CMake version         : 3.9.1
>
> --   CMake command         : /usr/bin/cmake
>
> --   Git version           : v0.1.11-9044-g9c426797a
>
> --   System                : Linux
>
> --   C++ compiler          : /usr/bin/c++
>
> --   C++ compiler version  : 7.2.0
>
> --   BLAS                  : Eigen
>
> --   CXX flags             :  -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -DONNX_NAMESPACE=onnx_c2 -O2 -fPIC -Wno-narrowing -Wno-invalid-partial-specialization -Wall -Wextra -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-type-limits -Wno-typedef-redefinition -Wno-unknown-warning-option -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wno-sign-compare -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-unused-variable -Wno-unused-function -Wno-unused-private-field -Wno-unused-result -Wno-inconsistent-missing-override -Wno-aligned-allocation-unavailable -Wno-error=deprecated-declarations -faligned-new
>
> --   Build type            : Release
> --   Compile definitions   :
> --   CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH     :
> --   CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX  : /usr/local
>
> --
> --   BUILD_CAFFE2          : ON
> --   BUILD_ATEN            : OFF
> --   BUILD_BINARY          : ON
> --   BUILD_CUSTOM_PROTOBUF : ON
> --     Link local protobuf : ON
> --   BUILD_DOCS            : OFF
> --   BUILD_PYTHON          : ON
> --     Python version      : 2.7.14
> --     Python includes     : /usr/include/python2.7
> --   BUILD_SHARED_LIBS     : ON
> --   BUILD_TEST            : OFF
> --   USE_ASAN              : OFF
> --   USE_ATEN              : OFF
> --   USE_CUDA              : ON
> --     CUDA static link    : OFF
> --     USE_CUDNN           : ON
> --     CUDA version        : 9.2
> --     cuDNN version       : 7.1.4
> --     CUDA root directory : /usr/local/cuda
> --     CUDA library        : /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcuda.so
> --     cudart library      : /usr/local/cuda/lib64/libcudart_static.a;-pthread;dl;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so
> --     cublas library      : /usr/local/cuda/lib64/libcublas.so;/usr/local/cuda/lib64/libcublas_device.a
> --     cufft library       : /usr/local/cuda/lib64/libcufft.so
> --     curand library      : /usr/local/cuda/lib64/libcurand.so
> --     cuDNN library       : /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcudnn.so
> --     nvrtc               : /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnvrtc.so
> --     CUDA include path   : /usr/local/cuda/include
> --     NVCC executable     : /usr/local/cuda/bin/nvcc
> --     CUDA host compiler  : /usr/bin/cc
> --     USE_TENSORRT        : OFF
> --   USE_ROCM              : OFF
> --   USE_EIGEN_FOR_BLAS    : ON
> --   USE_FFMPEG            : OFF
> --   USE_GFLAGS            : ON
> --   USE_GLOG              : ON
> --   USE_GLOO              : ON
> --     USE_GLOO_IBVERBS    : OFF
> --   USE_LEVELDB           : ON
> --     LevelDB version     : 1.20
> --     Snappy version      : ..
> --   USE_LITE_PROTO        : OFF
> --   USE_LMDB              : ON
> --     LMDB version        : 0.9.21
> --   USE_METAL             : OFF
> --   USE_MKL               :
> --   USE_MOBILE_OPENGL     : OFF
> --   USE_MPI               : ON
> --   USE_NCCL              : ON
> --     USE_SYSTEM_NCCL     : OFF
> --   USE_NERVANA_GPU       : OFF
> --   USE_NNPACK            : ON
> --   USE_OBSERVERS         : ON
> --   USE_OPENCL            : OFF
> --   USE_OPENCV            : ON
> --     OpenCV version      : 3.1.0
> --   USE_OPENMP            : OFF
> --   USE_PROF              : OFF
> --   USE_REDIS             : OFF
> --   USE_ROCKSDB           : OFF
> --   USE_ZMQ               : OFF
> --   Public Dependencies  : Threads::Threads;gflags;glog::glog
> --   Private Dependencies : nnpack;cpuinfo;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblmdb.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libleveldb.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsnappy.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnuma.so;opencv_core;opencv_highgui;opencv_imgproc;opencv_imgcodecs;opencv_videoio;opencv_video;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/libmpi_cxx.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/libmpi.so;gloo;gcc_s;gcc;dl
> -- Configuring done

Anything I am doing wrong? I have no idea how to fix this.

Thanks for the help

Comment: Ok, I got it working for me. I changed gcc to version 6, deleted the whole build dir and started a new compile from scratch. This time without any errors. Seems like a gcc-7 related issue.